# TYPO3: Generate in realURL multiple URLs with the same postVarSets in different levels

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

In my TYPO3 there are multiple storages with different sport activities.
The one belongs to place A, the other to place B with different content.
Now I would like to generate the followingURLs.

The first one is for general, the other one are specific.

```
/sport/golf
/place-a/sport/golf
/place-b/sport/golf
```

sport is decoded to `/sport-detail/controller/action/sport/`

I used the default lookUpTable, but the URLs cant be resolved.

```
'lookUpTable' => array(
    'table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_sport',
    'id_field' => 'uid',
    'alias_field' => "url",
    'addWhereClause' => ' AND deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0',
    'useUniqueCache' => 1,
    'languageGetVar' => 'L',
    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
    'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
        'strtolower' => 1,
        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
    ),
)
```

What is needed to create valid URLs, without golf-1 etc.. for all levels?

Comment: Please Provide your realurlConfiguration.php file and clairify about **place-a** and **place-b** are two different pages or not

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. Are "place-a" and "place-b" separate pages or are these additional parameters for your ext?
Also, could you provide the full RealURL config?

Depending on the targeted performance you could also just avoid using the UniqueCache...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I wrote a UserFunction that fulfills my needs. In this function I extend the given lookuptable function from realURL and fetch me the values yourself. 
The model has been renamed in the meantime to activity.
I do now save the detail pid for the show action and the storage pid in the sport model so I can search the whole URL path to find place name and lookup the storage pid. With the storage pid of the place I can find the right activity. And with a correct lookup in the database I can return a valid ID.
For SEO reasons I added a new field URL to the model that contains the string in the URL path. In the id2alias method I return the url value of the activity with the given ID.

I noticed one behavior that realURL doesn't find the correct entry in the caching table once all the parameters are hashed, so I had to exclude the activity GETvar from cHash generation.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cHashExcludedParameters'] = tx_myext_activity[activity]
```

After all this is my working setup :-)

RealURL config:

```
'GETvar' => 'tx_myext_activity[activity]',
'type' => 'user',
'languageGetVar' => 'L',
'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
'useUniqueCache' => 0,
'userFunc' => 'EXT:MyUserFunc.php:&MyUserFunc->main'
```

The UserFunction handles now the URL generation.

```
<?php

class MyUserFunc
{
    protected $sys_language_uid;
    protected $params;
    protected $localizedStrings;

    public function main($params, $ref)
    {
        if ($params) {
            $this->params = $params;
            $dirParts = $this->params['pObj']->dirParts;

            //language
            $this->sys_language_uid = 0;

            //is realUrl in encode or decode
            if ($this->params['decodeAlias']) {
                return $this->alias2id($this->params['value']);
            } else {
                return $this->id2alias($this->params['value']);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Generate URL param
     */
    protected function id2alias($value)
    {
        $sysLanguageToBuild = $this->params['pathParts'][0];

        //if not default, use l10n_parent with sysuid
        if ($sysLanguageToBuild > 0) {
            $additionalWhere = ' AND l10n_parent = ' . (int)$value;
            $additionalWhere .= ' AND sys_language_uid = ' . (int)$sysLanguageToBuild;
        } else {
            $additionalWhere = ' AND uid = ' . (int)$value;
        }

        $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
            'url',
            'tx_myext_domain_model_activity',
            'deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0' . $additionalWhere
        );

        $activityRow = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res);

        if (is_array($activityRow)) {
            return $activityRow['url'];
        }

        return 'undefined';
    }

    /**
     * Decode string to uid
     * respect activities with different pid
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return int
     */
    protected function alias2id($value)
    {
        $dirParts = $this->params['pObj']->dirParts; //get array of complete path
        $place = htmlspecialchars($this->params['pObj']->dirParts[2]); //get place

        //transform place string
        $place = strtolower($place);
        $place = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\s-._\/]/", "", $place);
        $place = trim(preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $place));

        //Query Place
        $placeRes = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
            'uid, activity_storage_page',
            'tx_myext_domain_model_place',
            'deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0 AND sys_language_uid = '. $this->sys_language_uid .
            ' AND LOWER(name) = "' . $place . '"'
        );

        $placeRow = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($placeRes);

        //Query Activity
        if (is_array($placeRow)) {
            $additionalWhere .= " AND tx_myext_domain_model_activity.pid = '" . (int)$placeRow['activity_storage_page'] . "'";
        }

        $additionalWhere = "  AND tx_myext_domain_model_activity.sys_language_uid = " . $this->sys_language_uid;
        $additionalWhere .= " AND tx_myext_domain_model_activity.url = '" . $value . "'";
        $additionalWhere .= " AND tx_myext_domain_model_activity.pid = '" . $pid . "'";


        $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
            'tx_myext_domain_model_activity.uid',
            'tx_myext_domain_model_activity',
            'deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0' . $additionalWhere
        );

        while ($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            return (int)$row['uid'];
        }

        //catch old URLs and return uid
        $additionalWhere = "  AND tx_myext_domain_model_activity.sys_language_uid = " . $this->sys_language_uid;
        $additionalWhere .= " AND tx_myext_domain_model_activity.name = '" . $value . "'";

        $resElse = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
            'tx_myext_domain_model_activity.uid',
            'tx_myext_domain_model_activity',
            'deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0' . $additionalWhere
        );
        while ($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($resElse)) {
            return (int)$row['uid'];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```